# STM32 ADC with DMA, DMA not writing data to memory location

Tags: assembly, stm32, dma, stm32f4discovery, adc

I am trying to use the ADC on STM32f407G-DISC1 board to read joystick x and y position on pins PA2 and PA1 respectively and store the values to a memory location using the DMA.

### I am configuring the ADC and DMA in the following way:

- Enable ADC1 clock (set ADC1EN in APB2ENR)
- Reset all ADC1 registers
- Set ADC clk prescaller to divide by 6 (set ADCPRE as 0b10 in ADC_CCR)
- Enable scan mode (set SCAN in ADC_CR1)
- Set CONT bit, continuous conversion (set CONT in ADC_CR2)
- Enable setting EOC flag after each conversion (set EOCS in ADC_CR2)
- Enable DMA and DDS (set DMA and DDS in ADC_CR2)
- Set 2 conversions as regular channel sequence length (set L as 0b1 in ADC_SQR1)
- Select order of conversions as -> PA1, PA2. (ADC_SQR3 register)
- Enable ADC1 (ADON bit in ADC_CR2)
- Wait 10ms for ADC to stabilize.
- Enable DMA2 clock (set bit 22 in AHB1ENR)
- Reset DMA_S0CR
- Wait for EN bit in DMA_S0CR to reset.
- Reset DMA_LISR and DMA_HISR registers.
- Select Channel 0 Stream 0 (CHSEL bits in DMA_S0CR)
- Select direction peripheral to memory (DIR bits in DMA_S0CR)
- Set peripheral data size and memory data size as half word, because ADC resolution is set to 12 bit. (PSIZE, MSIZE in DMA_S0CR)
- Set priority level as very high (PL bits in DMA_S0CR)
- Enable circular mode (CIRC bit in DMA_S0CR)
- Enable memory increment mode (MINC bit in DMA_S0CR)
- Set 2 as the number of data items to transfer (DMA_S0NDTR register)
- Set stream0 Peripheral address in DMA_S0PAR register. I set this address as `ADC1_BASE + ADC_DR`; So the data register of ADC1
- Set stream0 memory address in DMA_S0MAR as address of `JOYSTICK_POS`
- Enable Stream0, (EN bit in DMA_S0CR)
- Reset ADC1 status register (ADC_SR)
- Start conversion of regular channels on ADC1 (Set SWSTART in ADC_CR2)

##### As soon as I `Start conversion of regular channels on ADC1 (Set SWSTART in ADC_CR2)`

- The TCIF0 and HTIF0 flags get set in DMA2 LISR.
- These are transfer complete and half transfer flags and I don't know if these do anything to prevent future data transfers. These never clear.
- When I look at NDTR register of stream 0, the value does actually get decremented every time the EOC flag in ADC2 SR gets set, and also the NDTR value gets set back to 2 before it reaches 0 which is the expected behaviour and I suppose this means that the DMA acts like it is transfering data, however when I load data from JOYSTICK_POS into r6 and look at the value in the debugger it is always 0, meaning nothing actually got written to memory (**or at least not at the right location?**).
- I should also mention that the ADC is actually converting and puting what looks like the right data (according to physical joystick position) into the DR register and the data gets read by the DMA, because otherwise the OVR (overrun) flag would get set!

[STM32 reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

### Why does my DMA not transfer any data to JOYSTICK_POS?

#### Here is the code I am using to configure the ADC and DMA

```s
@RCC
.equ  RCC_BASE,           0x40023800
.equ  RCC_AHB1ENR,        0x30
.equ  RCC_APB2ENR,        0x44

@ GPIOA
.equ  GPIOA_BASE,         0x40020000
.equ  GPIO_ODR,           0x14
.equ  GPIO_BSRR,          0x18
.equ  GPIO_AFRL,          0x20
.equ  GPIO_AFRH,          0x24

@ ADC
.equ  ADC1_BASE,          0x40012000
.equ  ADC2_BASE,          0x40012100
.equ  ADC3_BASE,          0x40012200
.equ  ADC_SR,             0x0
.equ  ADC_CR1,            0x4
.equ  ADC_CR2,            0x8
.equ  ADC_DR,             0x4c
.equ  ADC_HTR,            0x24
.equ  ADC_LTR,            0x28
.equ  ADC_SQR1,           0x2c
.equ  ADC_SQR2,           0x30
.equ  ADC_SQR3,           0x34
.equ  ADC_SMPR1,          0x0C
.equ  ADC_SMPR2,          0x10
.equ  ADC_CCR,            0x04

@ DMA
.equ  DMA1_BASE,          0x40026000
.equ  DMA2_BASE,          0x40026400

.equ  DMA_LISR,           0x0
.equ  DMA_HISR,           0x4
.equ  DMA_S0CR,           0x10 + 0x18 * 0
.equ  DMA_S3CR,           0x10 + 0x18 * 3
.equ  DMA_S0_NDTR,        0x14 + 0x18 * 0
.equ  DMA_S0PAR,          0x18 + 0x18 * 0
.equ  DMA_S0M0AR,         0x1c + 0x18 * 0
.equ  DMA_S0M1AR,         0x20 + 0x18 * 0

// SysTick Timer definitions
.equ  SCS,                    0xe000e000
.equ  SCS_SYST_CSR,       0x10  // Control/Status register
.equ  SCS_SYST_RVR,       0x14  // Value to countdown from
.equ  SCS_SYST_CVR,       0x18  // Current value

.equ  SYSTICK_RELOAD_1MS,   15999  //1 msec at 16MHz ...  16 000 000 / 500 - 1

.section .text

JOYSTICK_POS: .word 0 @ This is where I want to store the 2 position values

_start:
  bl init_io
  bl init_tc
 
  bl init_adc1
  bl enable_adc1

  bl init_dma2
  bl dma2_joystick_config
  bl start_adc1

main:
  @ Load the word at JOYSTICK_POS into r6. This will stay 0 for ever
  ldr r6, JOYSTICK_POS 
  b main

dma2_joystick_config:
  push { r5, r6, lr }
  ldr r5, =DMA2_BASE
  @ N of data items to transfer: 2
  mov r6, #2
  str r6, [r5, #DMA_S0_NDTR]

  ldr r5, =DMA2_BASE
  ldr r6, =ADC1_BASE + ADC_DR
  str r6, [r5, #DMA_S0PAR]
  
  adr r6, JOYSTICK_POS
  str r6, [r5, #DMA_S0M0AR]

  @ Enable stream
  ldr r6, [r5, #DMA_S0CR]
  orr r6, #1
  str r6, [r5, #DMA_S0CR]
  pop { r5, r6, pc }

init_dma2:
  push { r5, r6, lr }
  @ Enable DMA2 clock
  ldr r5, =RCC_BASE
  ldr r6, [r5, #RCC_AHB1ENR]
  orr r6, #(1<<22)
  str r6, [r5, #RCC_AHB1ENR]

  ldr r5, =DMA2_BASE
  mov r6, #0
  str r6, [r5, #DMA_S0CR]
  wait_dma2_reset:
    ldr r6, [r5, #DMA_S0CR]
    tst r6, #1
    bne wait_dma2_reset
  
  mov r6, #0
  str r6, [r5, #DMA_LISR]
  str r6, [r5, #DMA_HISR]

  @ Channel 0, Stream 0
  @ CHSEL: 0, DIR: Peripheral to memmory, 
  mov r6, #0
 
  @ PSIZE, MSIZE hword
  orr r6, #(0b01<<11)
  orr r6, #(0b01<<13)

  @ Priority very high
  orr r6, #(0b11 << 16)

  @ CIRC MODE ENABLE
  orr r6, #(1<<8)

  @ TCIE = 1
  @ orr r6, #(1<<4)

  @ MEMORY INC
  orr r6, #(1<<10)
  str r6, [r5, #DMA_S0CR]
  pop { r5, r6, pc }

start_adc1:
  push { r5, r6, lr }
  ldr r5, =ADC1_BASE
  mov r6, #0
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_SR]
  @ START
  ldr r6, [r5, #ADC_CR2]
  orr r6, #(1<<30)
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_CR2]
  pop { r5, r6, pc }

enable_adc1:
  push { r5, r6, lr }
  ldr r5, =ADC1_BASE
  ldr r6, [r5, #ADC_CR2]
  orr r6, #1
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_CR2]
  @ Wait (10ms) for ADC to stabilize
  mov r0, #10
  bl delay
  pop { r5, r6, pc }

init_adc1:
  push { r5, r6, lr }
  @ Enable ADC1 clock
  ldr r5, =RCC_BASE
  ldr r6, [r5, #RCC_APB2ENR]
  orr r6, #(1<<8)
  str r6, [r5, #RCC_APB2ENR]

  ldr r5, =ADC1_BASE
  @ Reset adc registers
  mov r6, #0
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_CR2]
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_CR1]
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_SMPR1]
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_SMPR2]
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_SQR1]
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_SQR2]
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_SQR3]
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_CCR]
  
  @ CLK prescaler
  orr r6, #(2<<16)
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_CCR]
  
  @ CR1 settings
  @ SCAN MODE
  orr r6, #(1<<8)
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_CR1]

  @CR2 settings
  @ set CONT mode
  mov r6, #0b10
  @ EOC after each conversion
  orr r6, #(1<<10)
  @ Enable DMA, DDS
  orr r6, #(0b11<<8)
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_CR2]

  @ Two conversions
  mov r6, #(1<<20)
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_SQR1]

  @ Select order, PA1, PA2
  mov r6, #1
  orr r6, #(2 << 5)
  str r6, [r5, #ADC_SQR3]

  @ SAMPLE TIME
  @ mov r6, #9
  @ str r6, [r5, #ADC_SMPR2]

  pop { r5, r6, pc }

init_io:
  push { r5, r6, lr }

  @ Enable GPIOA clock
  ldr r5, =RCC_BASE
  ldr r6, [r5, #RCC_AHB1ENR]
  orr r6, #1
  str r6, [r5, #RCC_AHB1ENR]

  @ GPIOA_MODER  
  ldr r5, =GPIOA_BASE
  @ set pins 1,2 as analog
  ldr r6, [r5]
  orr r6, #(0b11 << 2)
  orr r6, #(0b11 << 4)
  str r6, [r5]

  pop { r5, r6, pc }


@ This is just code for the timer, so it's more clear what "bl delay" does
@ This works
init_tc:
  push {r5, r6, lr}
    ldr r6, =SCS

    ldr r5, =SYSTICK_RELOAD_1MS
    str r5, [r6, #SCS_SYST_RVR]

    ldr r5, =0
    str r5, [r6, #SCS_SYST_CVR]

    ldr r5, =5
    str r5, [r6, #SCS_SYST_CSR]

  pop {r5, r6, pc}

delay:
    push {r5, r6, lr}
    ldr r5, =SCS
  LOOPTC:   ldr r6, [r5, #SCS_SYST_CSR]
      tst r6, #0x10000
      beq LOOPTC

        subs r0, r0, 1
        bne LOOPTC
      pop {r5, r6, pc}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Wrong .section

I have solved this issue by moving `JOYSTICK_POS: .word 0`
from .text section which is basically the code section and gets stored in ROM, to the .data section which is meant for storing data and gets stored in RAM. So **the configuration was ok afterall.**